# Актуальность общих языковых меток, на примере C++

Tags: обсуждение, описание-метки

Итак, в тексте речь пойдёт о C++, но я предлагаю рассмотреть это и для других языков. Тем не менее, для меня сейчас C++ наиболее актуален.

Проблема: участники сообщества дают ответы по C++, которые актуальные для C++ версий 98/03 годов, а на замечание, что уже 2016 год на дворе и C++14 уже 2 года, а C++11 уже 5 лет, я получаю ответ в следующем стиле: метки C++11 и/или C++14 нет, значит используем старую версию. Я в корне с этим не согласен, человек задаёт вопрос по языку и, как правило, он не будет указывать версию стандарта.

Исключение составляют либо те, кто задаёт вопрос по конкретной фиче из конкретного стандарта, либо же те, кто что-то слышал про новые стандарты и старается лепить все новые метки.

В связи с чем я предлагаю: включить в описание метки C++ указание на то, что наличие данной метки подразумевает использование наиболее актуальной версии C++ и если требуется более старая, или же ещё не вышедшая версий, тогда нужно добавлять теги версий. [c++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) в одиночку должен означать только одно — актуальная версия языка. Мы должны просвещать вопрошающих, а не грузить их устаревшими ответами.

Comment: поддерживаю, для вопросов по С++03 нандо использовать метку [tag:с++03]

Comment: Мне нужен ответ по устаревший версии, но хотелось бы знать и как в новой это делается. Какие мои действия предполагаются? две метки или два вопроса или ..?

Comment: @4per, достаточно одной метки C++ и в теле вопроса явно указать, что хочется видеть решение как современным методом, так и методом из старого стандарта(можно указать либо стандарт, либо компилятор)

Comment: есть ISO С++ стандарт, а есть С++ версия, которая фактически компиляторами/популярными проектами поддерживается (в последние годы, это вероятно одно и то же, но так не всегда было). Если вы пишите под Винду на C++, то вероятно вы будете использовать только фичи, поддерживаемые Visual Studio для вашей версии Windows—для С++ (насколько я знаю) ситуация хорошая, но например для c99 раньше была плохая ситуация (не знаю что с c11). Писать, используя более современный стандарт обычно приятней, но не всегда есть возможность его использовать.

Comment: @jfs, тогда, вероятно, человек задающий вопрос должен указывать это в ограничениях. Если ограничений в вопросе нет, должна подразумеваться последняя версия, я на этом стою и больше ни на что не претендую.

Comment: @ixSci: использование  нового компилятора, который поддерживает самую последнюю версию языка, может быть более тяжёлым ограничением чем использование сторонних библиотек таких как boost.  Или вы считаете, что допустимо boost использовать, даже если вопрос не упоминает, что *нельзя* boost использовать? Так сложилось *сейчас* (в последние годы, но так не всегда было), что распространённые версии компиляторов поддерживают адекватно последние версии С++ стандарта. Метка языка по умолчанию должна отражать ту версию/набор фич, который люди фактически могут использовать— *сейчас* это одно и то же.

Comment: @jfs, что касается boost: я считаю, что неплохо его упомянуть в ответе, если с его помощью можно решить проблему проще и быстрее. Но это не обязательно, совершенно. Что касается всего остального: либо я не совсем Вас понимаю, либо Вы другими словами говорит то же самое, что я говорю: если отвечающий знает новый стандарт и в вопросе не указано обратное, ответ должен содержать свежую информацию.

Comment: Ответ должен содержать информацию, которую можно фактически использовать посетителями сайта. Если это практично использовать самую свежую версию, то можно самую свежую (выпущенную) версию использовать не упоминая это явно (иначе следует упомянуть используемую версию явно—никто не запрещает даже невыпущенные возможности демонстрировать, если явно это указано). Если вы используете новую фичу, которая не поддерживается универсально/требует специальных настроек при компиляции, то следует явно это упомянуть (что я должен g++ передать, чтобы собрать ваш код).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## В описании метки [c++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) о версиях *ничего* не сказано.

Ни о старых версиях, ни о новых. Так что причин **не** использовать С++11/14 без соответствующих меток нет и вы фактически правы.

Я поддерживаю предложение ограничиваться конкретными версиями *только* если добавлена метка с явной версией. **Но** когда их нет, предлагаю считать допустимой **любую** версию языка (в т. ч. неактуальную).

---

*Склонен считать, что более современное решение всё равно наберёт больше голосов и потому получит побольше внимания, но это отфонарно-эвристическое заявление, подкреплённое интуитивным представлением об аудитории метки [c++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b).*

Comment: Вы правы, более современное решение в теории наберёт больше плюсов, но на практике в нашем сообществе не всегда есть достаточное количество специалистов, чтобы на все вопросы отвечать в современном ключе. Кроме того, по непонятной мне причине, люди просто отвечают в старом ключе(то ли проще написать ответ про старую версию, то ли я не знаю)

Comment: @ixSci участники могут просто не знать о более свежих стандартах или не иметь достаточного опыта их использования. Это не повод притеснять их. А тех, кто знает и умеет, можно уведомить в комментариях. Чем ответить на аргумент "соответствующей метки нет", вы теперь знаете.

Comment: Нет, я видимо не совсем правильно выразился: я не говорю про тех, кто не знает нового стандарт, я говорю про тех, кто знает и тем не менее публикует ответ содержащий устаревшие сведения. Т.е. ни о каких притеснениях речи не идёт. А чем ответить я до сих пор не знаю, т.к. в метке нет указания на версию языка и люди могут продолжить это делать. С другой стороны, я могу с чистой совестью лепить минусы

Comment: @ixSci именно потому, что в метке нет никаких указаний на требуемую версию, аргумент "у вопроса нет метки С++11/14" не годится. Можно для них, конечно, добавить в описание что-то на манер "...включая новые стандарты", но я против только ими и ограничиваться. Вот.

Answer (score 6):

согласен, это правильное предложение, кроме того, поможет новичкам почаще задумываться о различиях в версиях, а учитывая бедственное положение с учебниками на русском языке (например, в 2016 году без исправлений издают книгу 2002 года), это очень нужно.

Comment: Новички все равно будут ставить просто [tag:c++]

Comment: @PashaPash, и ожидать ответы по старому стандарту, потому как в вузе только он например :)

Comment: @Grundy, но получать-то по новому ;)

Comment: @Grundy, если я ничего не путаю, то у нас сообщество программистов, и чтобы привлечь больше специалистов нам нужно нормально содержание ответов. Если мы будем идти на поводу у студентов, то и грамотных специалистов здесь не будет — не интересно. Интересно быть на передовой технологий, а не сидеть в затхлом тылу студенческих лабораторных работ.

Comment: @Grundy Студенты вообще не в курсе про стандарт. У них курс C++.  Надо делать лабы. А вы их тут какими-то стандартами смущаете.

Comment: @PashaPash, ну так и я про то же :-) стоит например в универе старый компилятор на компе на котором лабы принимают и все - ответ не подходит :)

Answer (score 2):

Я совершенно не возражаю против использования наиболее современного кода в ответах на вопросы, помеченные общей меткой [c++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b). Но есть нюансы, о которых, в том числе уже упоминали другие участники в ответах и комментариях. Попробую изложить их по пунктам:

- Автор вопроса может использовать старый компилятор/Стандарт, даже не особо догадываясь на этот счет. Например, студент факультета, где ПО не основная дисциплина. В таком случае, ответ, использующий новшества языка, просто может оказаться неработоспособным.
- Стандарт, принятый де-юре, может ещё не работать в должной степени с тем компилятором (производитель/версия), которым пользуется ТС. Т.е. человек работает с относительно современным C++, но всё же не с ультра-современным. Здесь важен вопрос временн*о*го лага между утверждением Стандарта и его реализацией. Пока эта дельта довольна мала, но, кто знает как будет дальше.
- Несмотря на то, что текущий Стандарт [c++14](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14), в ответах может быть полезно приводить и версию для более ранних стандартов, так сказать, для полноты картины. Это может быть полезно как для тех, кто выйдет на вопрос через google, так и для ТС, если он ещё не обозначил свою версию языка. Так же это продемонстрирует высокий уровень знаний отвечающего по эволюции языка. И коли уж ответ приведен, как для нового, так и для старого Стандартов, возмущений по поводу упоминания старого ни у кого быть не должно.
- Прописать в описании метки [c++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) о том, что её (эксклюзивное) использование подразумевает исключительно новый стандарт, мы, конечно, можем, но это ничего не даст, если вопрошающий не прочитает и не примет это к сведению. Т.е. такое описание может быть полезно именно для пресечения споров между постоянными участниками ruSO, кто будет знать этот нюанс. Однако на каждый вопрос нового участника нужно будет требовать у него уточнения, понимает ли он, что метка подразумевает именно текущий Стандарт.