# Добавим HTML5 синонимом к HTML, CSS3 — к CSS

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, метки, синонимы-меток

Постоянно сталкиваюсь с тем что

- либо вопросы помечены обоими метками [html](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) и [html5](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5), [css](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) и [css3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css3).
- либо вопросы помечены одной из них.

И если честно не вижу смысла в этом "ноевом ковчеге". У нас уже давно широко поддерживается HTML5 и CSS3. И даже если вопрос очень старый на него прекрасно можно предлагать решения на flexbox, градиенты или с синтаксисом HTML5, если там явно не спрашивается про IE7 или что-то в этом роде. Поэтому предлагаю сделать соответствующие метки синонимами.

---

Для тех кто думает, что появится когда-нибудь css4 делюсь новостью: **никогда** не будет css4, подобно монолитному css2.1. Дело в том что css3 также как такового не тоже существует. Существуют Level 3 отдельных модулей и всё. То что под [css3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css3) имеют ввиду какой-либо из десятка модулей, это не означает, что существует монолитный css3.

Подробней можно почитать:

- [A word about CSS4](http://www.xanthir.com/b4Ko0)
- [Why there is no CSS4 - explaining CSS Levels](https://rachelandrew.co.uk/archives/2016/09/13/why-there-is-no-css4-explaining-css-levels/)

---

А по поводу HTML6. Кто-то реально думает что будут выходить версии HTML с такой же скоростью как выходят версии C++, C#, Java, PHP, … (любой язык программирования)? И что в ближайшем будущем уже намечается что-то? Мне видится, что они будут выходить достаточно редко, чтобы когда мы говорили [html](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html), то всем понятно, что вопрос с 99.99% про [html5](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5), если не указано иного.

---

Comment: Скорость появления версий не важна. Важна возможность их разделения. Ваше предложение лишает нас такой возможности.

Comment: @alexolut а какой практический смысл в разделении меток? Подавляющее большинство вопросов всё равно касаются html вообще, а не какой-то его конкретной версии. Если выйдет html6, то, уверен, большинство авторов вопросов с меткой html5 будут не против увидеть html6-ответы на свои вопросы. Если вдруг появится вопрос по какой-то конкретной версии, что мешает ограничиться соответствующим упоминанием в тексте вопроса?

Comment: @andreymal метки как раз введены, чтобы уменьшить количество упоминаний в теле самого вопроса.

Comment: @alexolut и таки какой в этом практический смысл?

Comment: @andreymal в наличии меток или в чём?

Comment: @alexolut естественно. Метка html5 же всё равно не выполняют свою задачу, что я разъяснил в своём первом комментарии.

Comment: @andreymal версионные метки появляются, когда разработчики активно используют одновременно разные версии и на этом нужно сделать акцент. Допустим, если сейчас уже все используют html5, и никакого html6 еще нет в природе, то ставить одновременно голую html и html5 смысла не много. Но делать их синонимами всё же нельзя. О версионных метках есть [вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3826/176217) на Мете, кстати.

Comment: @alexolut это всё лишь в теории. На практике никто так не делает. Никто не использует несколько версий html. Все используют одну версию — последнюю. Если вдруг в редких случаях нужна поддержка старых браузеров, код пишут под версию браузера, а не под версию html/css — отдельные элементы html5 можно найти даже в IE5.5. Когда появится html6, все сразу станут использовать его после обновления браузеров. Опять же, я разъяснил это в своём первом комментарии. Метка html5 замусорена вопросами, которые никак не касаются собственно html5, и в текущем виде абсолютно бесполезна. (С css3 всё аналогично)

Comment: @andreymal пишите отдельный ответ, посмотрим, что скажут другие участники.

Comment: @andreymal Абсолютно согласен с вашей точкой зрения, поэтому тоже рекомендую написать его отдельным ответом.

Answer (score 10):

Мне кажется, что не очень правильно делать синонимами общую метку и метку, завязанную на конкретную версию. Вот выйдет в широкие массы [html6](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html6) например, его тоже захочется объединить с [html](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html)? Если так, то мы получим [html5](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5) == [html6](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html6). Сомневаюсь, что это действительно то, что хочется получить в итоге.

То, что на текущий момент [css2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css2) и [css](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) являются синонимами я могу объяснить следующей причиной: css2 был принят в 1998 году, а Stack Overflow появился только в 2008. Логично предположить, что вопросы касательно [ccs1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ccs1) уже мало кого (читай как "никого") интересовали, т.о [css2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css2) разумно было осинонимировать с [css](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css).

Логично предположить, что версионные метки на вопросах появляются в основном в период перехода с одной версии на другую. Но если с каждым выходом новой версии `X` (становления её как основной в промышленности) мы будем добавлять [ccsx](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ccsx) как синоним [css](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css), то вопросы по старым версиям уже нельзя будет отличить от вопросов по текущей версии.

Я считаю, что если версия не важна - надо просто ставить общую метку на вопрос. В ином случае - версионную метку (вероятно с добавлением основной). Ваше же предложение просто сотрёт эти границы. Чтобы оно не ломало существующую историю вопросов придётся одновременно с добавлением нового версионного синонима отменять старый, а это скорее всего невозможно, т.к. человек, задающий вопросу метку [css2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css2) автоматически получит на вопросе метку [css](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) (т.к. синоним уже задан). И при отмене синонима вернуть вопросу метку [css2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css2) станет затруднительно.

Дополнительно рекомендую ознакомиться со связанным вопросом по версионным меткам: [Актуальность общих языковых меток, на примере C++](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3826/176217)

Comment: [tag:css2] является синонимом [tag:css] и ничего. Плюс категорически несогласен, потому что обычно каждая следующая версия выходит редко и очень хорошо совместима с предыдущей. Плюс когда мы говорим [tag:html], то обычно подразумеваем [html5]. Когда выйдет и будет широко адаптирован [html6], то так и сделаем.

Comment: Кстати по поводу [tag:cssx] категорически не согласен. В самом [tag:css3] уже целесообразно рассматировать определённый раздел вроде [tag:css-animation] или [tag:flexbox] и т.д. С каждой последующей версией думаю даже w3c будет работать над отдельными модулями, а не просто будет css4, css5 и т.д.

Comment: Обновил вопрос, считаю сравнение с C++ в данном случае неуместным.