# Объединить метки [php] и [php5] [php7]

Tags: предложение, синонимы-меток

Может быть стоит объединить эти метки? Вопросов по этим меткам задаются мало и редко, когда решение вопроса требует конкретизировать версию. Например у java6, java7 такого нет.

Кстати на https://stackoverflow.com вроде как php5 и php объединены.

Comment: Вроде в 7 много всего нового появилось?

Comment: Ничего себе там [синонимов](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/synonyms) у англомериканцев.

Comment: @Qwertiy добавилось много, но 7 практически всё поддерживает что было в 5. Даже многие старые cms работают на 7 версии. Да и честно я пока не сталкивался с проблемами совместимости.... Поэтому я не вижу смысла делать метки отдельно.

Comment: @älёxölüt мое мнение и правильно сделали)

Comment: @älёxölüt имхо, [PHP-FPM](https://php-fpm.org/) не стоило синонимизировать, это вполне себе отдельная вещь. Например, как в Питоне ipython / jupyter.

Comment: @älёxölüt, избавляются понемногу, чтобы всё под одну метку сгрести, а потом заигнорить :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метки объединять не надо. В php7 добавилось довольно много нового и вполне могут возникать вопросы по конкретным нововведениям этой версии, которые стоит помечать соответствующей меткой. Аналогичные метки есть и по другим языкам, например: [ecmascript-6](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6).

Answer (score 0):

Чем дальше в будущее, тем меньше общего между [php5](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php5) и [php](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php).

[php5](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php5) — старая версия языка. Настолько старая, что с начала 2019 года её [перестанут поддерживать](https://secure.php.net/supported-versions.php). Такую метку ставят, когда вопрос нужно решить строго на этой версии. Думаю, что эту метку лучше оставить.

Метка без версии, как [php](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php), подразумевает последнюю, актуальную версию. Поэтому, сейчас [php7](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php7) — это то же, что и просто [php](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php). Кажется, можно синонимизировать.

Когда выйдет PHP 8, метка [php7](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php7) обретёт самостоятельный смысл и мы её отвяжем от [php](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php). Тогда новые вопросы можно будет помечать теперь устаревшей меткой [php7](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php7).

Comment: Не согласен. К тому же, синонимизация так не работает ведь.

Comment: @Qwertiy как не работает?

Comment: Как в последнем абзаце написано.

Comment: @Qwertiy отменить синонимы можно. Понятно, что старым вопросам это не вернёт метку php7, так это и не нужно. Зато на новые вопросы её можно будет ставить.

Comment: Согласен с Qwertiy, не стоит синонимизировать метку без номера с текущей последней версией. Версионные метки пусть живут отдельно, а безциферная имеет в виду последнюю актуальную версию, но без привязки по меткам средствами SO. Собственно, вероятно, [дубликат](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3826/176217).

Comment: "как php, подразумевает последнюю, актуальную версию" Впервые про это слышу)

Comment: @Suvitruf что, в PHP не принято последнюю версию использовать? )

Comment: @NickVolynkin не принято под [tag:php] подразумевать последнюю версию. Ну и да, я до сих пор на 5.6 сижу :D

Comment: @Suvitruf ок, буду знать )